# Can I lookup a related field using a Q object in the Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, orm

In Django, can I re-use an existing Q object on multiple models, without writing the same filters twice?

I was thinking about something along the lines of the pseudo-Django code below, but did not find anything relevant in the documentation :

```
class Author(Model):
  name = TextField()
  company_name = TextField()

class Book(Model):
  author = ForeignKey(Author)

# Create a Q object for the Author model
q_author = Q(company_name="Books & co.")

# Use it to retrieve Book objects
qs = Book.objects.filter(author__matches=q_author)
```

If that is not possible, can I extend an existing Q object to work on a related field? Pseudo-example :

```
# q_book == Q(author__company_name="Books & co.")
q_book = q_author.extend("author")

# Use it to retrieve Book objects
qs = Book.objects.filter(q_book)
```

The only thing I've found that comes close is using a subquery, which is a bit unwieldy :

```
qs = Book.objects.filter(author__in=Author.objects.filter(q_author))
```

Comment: I don't understand your use of a `Q` object here, your first query looks like it just needs to be `author__company_name="Books and Co"`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have made it clearer. My real Q object is pretty large (much more than my example), and I would really like to be able to reuse it on related models without having to redefine it twice.

Comment: I understand exactly why you want to use the same Q object but against a related field as I wanted to do the same today. Found this question, sad that no answer other than dictionary mangling, which doesn't work in the case of complex nested Q objects with a bunch of & and | and ~.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell by your comment, it just looks like you're trying to pass a set of common arguments to multiple filters, to do that you can just unpack a dictionary

The values in the dictionary can still be q objects if required as if it were a value you would pass in to the filter argument normally

```
args = { 'author__company_name': "Books & co" }
qs = Book.objects.filter(**args)

args['author_name'] = 'Foo'
qs = Book.objects.filter(**args)
```

To share this between different models, you'd have to do some dictionary mangling

```
author_args = { k.lstrip('author__'): v for k, v in args.items }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am actually using that pattern in some places. My goal here is rather to be able to pass the same set of filters to multiple _models_. Obviously having `Book.objects.filter(**args)` and `Author.objects.filter(**args)` with the same `args` do not work out of the box, but that's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @F.X. - Ah right I see now, I don't think theres any  better way than using the unpack in the same/similar way, regardless you'll run into the same issues of ensuring the fields exist in both models

Comment: The fields are actually from the `Author` model in both cases, but I want to filter `Books` through the related `author` field using the exact same set of filters. I guess that there is no way of doing this then...

Comment: @F.X. - I've added some ugly hackery which is what I think the closest you'll find I'm afraid, might be worth rethinking the actual problem you're trying to solve with this solution..

Comment: Thanks! It just seemed like it would be a good idea to be able to share Q objects like this, but hacking dicts like that is going to be hard to maintain going forward. I'm still going to accept the answer for future readers as it is the closest to what I actually want! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
books = Book.objects.filter(author__company_name="Books & co")
```

Comment: This works, of course, but I edited my question to make it clear that I wanted to avoid having to redefine filters like your answer. Sorry!